# Leaflet customcontrol - Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet, ngx-leaflet

I need to integrate a custom form control in my Angular2+ component:

```
export class HeatMapComponent {
...
  onMapReady(map: L.Map) {
    let div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
    let info = new L.Control();
    info.onAdd = () => {
      return div;
    };
    info.addTo(map);
  }
}
```

And the .hmtl file like this:

```
    <div class="map container-fluid"
     leaflet [leafletOptions]="options"
     [leafletLayersControl]="layersControl"
     (leafletMapReady)="onMapReady($event)">
</div>
```

The .css:

```
...

    .info {
      padding: 2rem 1rem;
      margin-left: 70rem;
      margin-right: 15rem;
      font: 1rem/1.5rem Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      background: white;
      background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
      box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

In the leaflet documentation it's written in JS like this:

```
var info = L.control();info.onAdd = function (map) {
this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create a div with a class "info"
this.update();
return this._div;
}; 
// method that we will use to update the control based on feature properties passed
info.update = function (props) {
    this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>US Population Density</h4>' +  (props ?
        '<b>' + props.name + '</b><br />' + props.density + ' people / mi<sup>2</sup>'
        : 'Hover over a state');
};

info.addTo(map);
```

Why can't I integrate the addTo method in my onMapReady? I don't get any errors but nothing is displayed on my map.

Comment: There's a typo in your component in your ```onMapReady``` function. ```this.infoControl = L.control;``` should be ```this.infoControl = L.control();```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved this problem the solution is:

```
onMapReady(map: leaflet.Map) { 
let div = leaflet.DomUtil.create('div', 'infoControl'); 
let info = new leaflet.Control(); info.onAdd = () => { 
return div; 
   }; 
console.log(div); 
info.addTo(map); 
}
```